# An example of Angular 2 animation ended callback function

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am trying to create a function that will be triggered at the end of an animation in Angular 2 (I am using the latest angular cli).

I have been on the [Angular Animations](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html#!#animation-callbacks) to gain some understanding of how this would be implemented by assigning the trigger with a callback
in my example of code I have a component that is animated onto the page. the code is has follows:

```js
//first.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, state, style, animate, transition } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-first',
  templateUrl: './first.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./first.component.css'],
  host: {
    '[@routeAnimation]': 'true',
    '[style.display]': "'block'",
    '[style.position]': "'absolute'"
  },
  animations: [
    trigger('routeAnimation', [
      state('*', style({transform: 'translateX(0)', opacity: 1})),
      transition('void => *', [style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)', opacity: 0}),animate(500)]),
      transition('* => void', animate(500, style({transform: 'translateX(100%)', opacity: 0})))
    ])
  ]
})
export class FirstComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  myFunc() {
  // call this function at the end of the animation.
 }

}
```

the html is simply a div

```xml
<div class="w9914420">
  <h2>
     first-component Works!
  </h2>
</div>
```

To be honest I am not too familiar with JavaScript so any help or a quick example would help me gain a better understanding of Angular 2.

Answer (score 49):

This is working example:

```js
import {Component, NgModule, Input, trigger, state, animate, transition, style, HostListener } from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector : 'toggle',
  animations: [
    trigger('toggle', [
      state('true', style({ opacity: 1; color: 'red' })),
      state('void', style({ opacity: 0; color: 'blue' })),
      transition(':enter', animate('500ms ease-in-out')),
      transition(':leave', animate('500ms ease-in-out'))
    ])
  ],
  template: `
  <div class="toggle" [@toggle]="show" 
        (@toggle.start)="animationStarted($event)"
        (@toggle.done)="animationDone($event)"
     *ngIf="show">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>`
})
export class Toggle {
  @Input() show:boolean = true;
  @HostListener('document:click')
  onClick(){
    this.show=!this.show;
  }

  animationStarted($event) {
    console.log('Start');
  }

  animationDone($event) {
    console.log('End');
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <toggle>Hey!</toggle>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {

}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App, Toggle ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Pgblp0eKq8T54BLdJtqw?p=preview)

Comment: Good example of this using this method with NgModule, thank you PatrickJane.

Comment: I actually created a PLUNKER (plnkr.co/edit/d1UQcN?p=preview) and implemented the callback functions and added the start and done triggers to the user/component.ts file. I noticed a strange behaviour to the User component transition. This implementation causes a slight delay when the component is transition on the stage to remove the dashboard component. Any ideas to why this might be happening? removing the callback implementation sets back things to normal?

Comment: Have a look at my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/d1UQcN?p=preview) tell me if you find the same issue as stated in my above comment

Answer (score 20):

Now Angular2's supported `(@animation.start)` and `(@animation.done)` to tap into animation events.

For example, you can use `(@routeAnimation.start)=onStart($event)`, `(@routeAnimation.done)=onDone($event)` in the first.component.html.

You can find out more at [here](https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers#animation-callbacks).

Also you can see a simple example with the first.component.ts on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZChA6phDsazGwRKbjuxj?p=preview).

Hope this help!

Comment: So how would you define the routeAnimation onstart and done functions in first.component.ts for example?

Comment: I appreciate the example, and demonstrates how I would implement with my code

Comment: actually created a PLUNKER (https://plnkr.co/edit/d1UQcN?p=preview) and implemented the callback functions and added the start and done triggers to the user/component.ts file. I noticed a strange behaviour to the User component transition. This implementation causes a slight delay when the component is transition on the stage to remove the dashboard component. Any ideas to why this might be happening? removing the callback implementation sets back things to normal?

Comment: Have a look at my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/d1UQcN?p=preview) tell me if you find the same issue as stated in my above comment