# How in angular 2+, dynamically manage the addition of animations (:enter and :leave) under certain conditions?

Tags: angular, angular2-animation

I'm working on an animation for :enter and :leave from the pages.

```
import { animate, AnimationEntryMetadata, state, style, transition, trigger } from '@angular/core';

export const slideInDownAnimation: AnimationEntryMetadata = trigger('routeAnimation', [
    state('*',
        style({
            transform: 'translateY(0)'
        })
    ),
    transition(':enter', [
        style({
            transform: 'translateY(100%)'
        }),
        animate('.5s linear')
    ]),
    transition(':leave', [
        animate('.5s linear', style({
            transform: 'translateY(-100%)'
        }))
    ])
]);
```

In components:

```
import { slideInDownAnimation } from './../route-animation/animations';
import { Component, OnInit, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-building',
  templateUrl: './building.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./building.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    slideInDownAnimation
  ]
})
export class BuildingComponent implements OnInit {

  @HostBinding('@routeAnimation') routeAnimation = true;
  @HostBinding('style.display') display = 'block';
  @HostBinding('style.position') position = 'absolute';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

And this animation is reused in several components.

In each of these components there is a button to go to the next page with the same animation.

I need to create common conditions for these components with animation, so that the animation works only when these buttons are pressed. Can with the help of some kind of common service.

This animation works every time you go to animation pages, and I just need the animation to work only when these buttons are clicked.

Comment: add click-listeners to your buttons, and toggle variables for leaving and entering using a class-host binding.

Comment: @John It is necessary that a click in one component be tracked in other similar components. For this I can use rxjs. But how do I start or stop an animation by changing a variable?
How do I pass the value of a variable to @HostBinding?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question, but you can use `[class.leave]="leaving"` in your html, and then a `(click)="toggleLeave()"` which toggles the `leaving`-varible. And the same for enter

Comment: Maybe this question can help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40246853/an-example-of-angular-2-animation-ended-callback-function

Comment: @John Thanks, I'll take a look