# Angular Animation pause domUpdate while animating

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I have a simple observable representing the length of a list.

As it evolve, I want to animate increments and decrements of that number, for example:

- the number increases
- I fade out the previous value
- I fade in the new value

But during the fade out, I can see the next value being already updated. The 2 ways I found to solve the problem are :

- manually manage value update by subscribing to observable from the TS controller
- the rxjs operator `delayWhen` to conditionnaly delay the value update ([here](https://asirko.github.io/anim/morphing-object) is a french explanation of that method there is code as example)

Both seem too complicated for what I want. So here my question.

**Is there a way to block DOM updates while animating an element?**

Comment: you can assign the new data in the callback function `(@animation.done)`. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40246853/an-example-of-angular-2-animation-ended-callback-function

Comment: It exactly what I mean by manually manage the value. It's work, but I would prefer a way to freeze the dom while animating...

Comment: It's a very interesting question but I think it's either not possible or there is no easy solution out there yet. I personally had the same issue and implemented an abstract service that is doing all your "manuall-manage" stuff out of the box.