# how to execute a sequence of animation in angular ngFor

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-animations

## Background

Hey, I am currently trying to animate a svg using angular animation, it has several paths and it may change in the future or even be dynamically updated from a serve so I made a list of all paths and added in my type script and using ngFor I add them one by one in the HTML. each path represents a letter.

## The problem

I need to add two animations to the svg

- dashing them in and out and filling them with color.
- make one path of them move in a diagonal line continuously and non-stop after the first animation ends.
  each one of these tasks I did Separately and working just fine as intended, and even together it all works as intended except I can't make the second animation endless and continues.

## what I tried and did already

- I tried adding two triggers, one trigger for the entire path list and the other for just that one path I want to move but it resulted in making only that path shows and not any other path.

```js
    const listAnimation = trigger('listAnimation', [
      transition('* <=> *', [
        query(':enter',
        [ 
          style({
                  'stroke-dashoffset': "647", 
                  fill:"#ff000000"
                }),
          stagger('60ms',
                  animate('4500ms ease-out', 
                          style({'stroke-dashoffset': "0", fill:'green'})
                          )
                  )
        ]
        ),
        query('#p2',
        [ 
          style({
                  transform: 'translate(0px, 0px)'
                }),
          stagger('60ms', 
                  animate('1500ms ease-out', 
                          style({transform: 'translate(-25px, -25px)'})
                          )
                  )
        ]
        )
      ])
    ]);
```

HTML

```html
    <svg *ngIf="show2" id="Logo" [@listAnimation]="pathes.length" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-30 -30 765 264" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path *ngFor="let path of pathes; index as i" id={{path.id}} attr.d={{path.d}} stroke="#737373" stroke-width="5" />
    </svg>
```

- I tried using flags to indicate the end and start of the animation but it resulted in starting the whole sequence not just the moving part.

## what I want and What's Expected

any way that allow me to do the above two animations after each other and repeating the second one endlessly.

## code

Here is My [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/animation-testingg?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) code of what I did so far, feel free to edit.

- note: works best on chrome.

Answer (score 0):

turns out all I need to do is either add both  query from what i did in a "group" *[See this link "Angular Group"](https://angular.io/api/animations/group) to make it go in parallel with eachother.
or just simply create a new trigger on a div that contains both "svg and path" then make a new animation const calling it after the first animation which will make it occur one after the other "[See this link "angular Animation"](https://angular.io/guide/complex-animation-sequences)
as for the endless loop all is to make a function that is called when the animation ends which in return will result in changing the state which will restart the animation again and so on "[See this link "Angular triggers"](https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers) and [This Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40246853/an-example-of-angular-2-animation-ended-callback-function)